# Do not Get value from value vind in vueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In the selected line [ value bind syntax ] ok?
if so then why I do not get the supplier id when I console it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cfV3.png)

Comment: It took you more effort to snip a screen shot and upload it than it would have to post the actual code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Here u missed adding `v-model` to select.

add a variable selectedValue and 

update your code like this

```js
console.log(this.selectedValue)
```

```html
<select v-model="selectedValue>
   <option>Select one Value</select>
   <option v-for="cat in allCategories" :value="cat.id">{{cat.name}}</option>
</select>
```